How to identify the cause of InnoDB Runtime Locks in Azure Mysql Flexible Server?
I am using Azure MySQL Flexible Server and encountering InnoDB runtime locks that seem to cause delays or failures in my database operations.
How can I determine which queries or operations are causing the InnoDB locks?
What tools or commands can I use to further investigate the lock wait issues in Azure MySQL?
Are there any Azure MySQL Flexible Server specific logs, metrics, or insights available for runtime locks?
Checked for long-running queries using:
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
Verified InnoDB engine status:
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

Also, long running locks will show up as "slow" queries in the SlowLog

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
